# MSAccess two page forms with different headers

Tags: ms-access-2010

Microsoft Access form.  I have two tables with mega data.  I have created a report the fields where the first page includes all the information from a contractor from table1 (name, address, contract number, trade, insurance info, etc..) and the bottom third of the page1 includes information from the second table payroll data (week ending, how many employees worked that week, total hours) it fits about 20 weeks.

I need to change it so that page 2 and any subsequent pages have a different header which includes less information (i.e. only the contractors name and trade, and then continues with the information from week 21 onwards from table 2 and adds as many pages as needed to complete the dataset from weeks table2.

I created the report and linked table1 to table2 by the contractors id, it reports the data correctly but page two and beyond has the same header.